# Making a request to a RESTful API using Python

Tags: python, rest

I have a RESTful API that I have exposed using an implementation of Elasticsearch on an EC2 instance to index a corpus of content. I can query the search by running the following from my terminal (MacOSX):

```
curl -XGET 'http://ES_search_demo.com/document/record/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "text": {
            "record.document": "SOME_JOURNAL"
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "record.articleTitle": "farmers"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}'
```

How do I turn above into a API request using `python/requests` or `python/urllib2` (not sure which one to go for - have been using urllib2, but hear that requests is better...)? Do I pass as a header or otherwise?

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io):

```
import requests
url = 'http://ES_search_demo.com/document/record/_search?pretty=true'
data = '''{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "text": {
            "record.document": "SOME_JOURNAL"
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "record.articleTitle": "farmers"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}'''
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

Depending on what kind of response your API returns, you will then probably want to look at `response.text` or `response.json()` (or possibly inspect `response.status_code` first). See the quickstart docs [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/), especially [this section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: @ParveenShukhala "Requests officially supports Python 2.6–2.7 & 3.3–3.5, and runs great on PyPy." -- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/

Comment: As it's JSON you are sending, you can use the json parameter rather than data like so:  response = requests.post(url, json=data)

Answer (score 119):

Using [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) makes it simple.

1. Call the API
2. Assuming the API returns a JSON, parse the JSON object into a
   Python dict using `json.loads` function
3. Loop through the dict to extract information.

[Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module provides you useful function to loop for success and failure.

`if(Response.ok)`: will help help you determine if your API call is successful (Response code - 200)

`Response.raise_for_status()` will help you fetch the http code that is returned from the API.

Below is a sample code for making such API calls. Also can be found in [github](https://gist.github.com/vinovator/98b0fb7eb30805595bd6). The code assumes that the API makes use of digest authentication. You can either skip this or use other appropriate authentication modules to authenticate the client invoking the API.

```
#Python 2.7.6
#RestfulClient.py

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import json

# Replace with the correct URL
url = "http://api_url"

# It is a good practice not to hardcode the credentials. So ask the user to enter credentials at runtime
myResponse = requests.get(url,auth=HTTPDigestAuth(raw_input("username: "), raw_input("Password: ")), verify=True)
#print (myResponse.status_code)

# For successful API call, response code will be 200 (OK)
if(myResponse.ok):

    # Loading the response data into a dict variable
    # json.loads takes in only binary or string variables so using content to fetch binary content
    # Loads (Load String) takes a Json file and converts into python data structure (dict or list, depending on JSON)
    jData = json.loads(myResponse.content)

    print("The response contains {0} properties".format(len(jData)))
    print("\n")
    for key in jData:
        print key + " : " + jData[key]
else:
  # If response code is not ok (200), print the resulting http error code with description
    myResponse.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Last portion with iteration over keys will not always work because JSON document may have array as a top level element. So, it would be an error to try to get `jData[key]`

Comment: @DenisTheMenace if it is an array, how would I loop around it?

Comment: @qasimalbaqali the same way you loop over dictionary. But array elements will be simply `jData`, not `jData[key]`

Comment: Sidenote: If your API returns a large JSON response, you can pretty print it like this: 
`print(json.dumps(jData, indent=4, sort_keys=True))`

Comment: Under python3, the following was spit out 'JSON must be str not bytes'. This is fixed by decoding the output, i.e. json.loads(myResponse.content.decode('utf-8')).  Also you should wrap key and jData key with str() so when the RESTful API returns integers, it doesn't complain.

Answer (score 13):

So you want to pass data in body of a GET request, better would be to do it in POST call.  You can achieve this by using both Requests.

Raw Request

```
GET http://ES_search_demo.com/document/record/_search?pretty=true HTTP/1.1
Host: ES_search_demo.com
Content-Length: 183
User-Agent: python-requests/2.9.0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "text": {
            "record.document": "SOME_JOURNAL"
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "record.articleTitle": "farmers"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}
```

Sample call with Requests

```
import requests

def consumeGETRequestSync():
data = '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "text": {
            "record.document": "SOME_JOURNAL"
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "record.articleTitle": "farmers"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}'
url = 'http://ES_search_demo.com/document/record/_search?pretty=true'
headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
# call get service with headers and params
response = requests.get(url,data = data)
print "code:"+ str(response.status_code)
print "******************"
print "headers:"+ str(response.headers)
print "******************"
print "content:"+ str(response.text)

consumeGETRequestSync()
```

Comment: got a dead link there

Comment: headers variable should be used: requests.get(...headers = headers, ....)

Answer (score 12):

Below is the program to execute the rest api in python-

```
import requests
url = 'https://url'
data = '{  "platform": {    "login": {      "userName": "name",      "password": "pwd"    }  } }'
response = requests.post(url, data=data,headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
print(response)
sid=response.json()['platform']['login']['sessionId']   //to extract the detail from response
print(response.text)
print(sid)
```

Comment: Not work for me.  Instead I use the advice here.  Seems work: https://realpython.com/api-integration-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

For now, [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) is a better option than requests. It has broadly request-compatible API, supports async, HTTP/2 and has a good performance. It is used by, for example, *python-telegram-bot* - a popular client for Telegram bots.

```py
import httpx
url = 'http://ES_search_demo.com/document/record/_search?pretty=true'
data = {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "text": {
            "record.document": "SOME_JOURNAL"
          }
        },
        {
          "text": {
            "record.articleTitle": "farmers"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": [],
  "facets": {}
}
response = httpx.post(url, json=data)
print(response.json())
```

However, if you want to request Elasticsearch, it's better to use specific elasticsearch API clients: [elasticsearch](https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch/) or high-level [elasticsearch-dsl](https://pypi.org/project/elasticsearch-dsl/)