# PLONE to call and perform REST API calls on another application

Tags: plone

[image]

we are developing a plone interface to consume REST API services from a web application.
Users login to plone and be able to access the REST API & perform some actions on the "Another Web Application" via REST API calls. Please find the graphical representation attached here.

Query 1)What and all the Plone programming documentation I needed to refer to design & develop such a solution in Plone? that is,access and perform actions on REST APIs, from a PLONE based Solution.

Query: 2) What all are the different technologies I need to refer to learn & program in PLONE and python to achieve this work using PLONE framework?
Please share your valuable inputs and suggestion to move in the right direction.

Please refer the attached block diagram of the proposed solution.

.

Answer (score 1):

In a first step you could register a "view" for authenticated users in Plone. In the view's Python module you could call the restful api of the other web application.

Helpful resources are:

1. Creating a basic package (Plone Addon) with mr.bob and bobtemplates.plone: https://github.com/plone/bobtemplates.plone
2. Creating and registering a view: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/views/browserviews.html#creating-and-registering-a-view
3. Call a resful api with python: [Making a request to a RESTful API using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python)
4. If you have to collect data from your plone site to transmit to the restful api f.e. user data, then plone.api is the standarized way. http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone.api/docs/

Answer (score -1):

Recently a very nice module developed, exactly for the purpose you mentioned here, in Plone. It's called "plone.restapi".
github link: https://github.com/plone/plone.restapi