# Unable to run a python restful program

Tags: python, rest

I am using "Python 3.5" from the website "https://www.python.org/" and when i try to run the program provided by [HVS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32721995/3151189) it does not work.

```
C:\Users\sdixit23>python C:\Users\sdixit23\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Shyam\NotWorking\restfulclient2.py
File      "C:\Users\sdixit23\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Shyam\NotWorking\restfulclient2.py", line 26 print key + " : " + jData[key] ^ 
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print' C:\Users\sdixit23>
```

Could you please share another version of a restful API that can work.

[This question was also asked here in anothe thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35013296/3151189)

Comment: "Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" - looks like you need to use python 2.7 (as mentioned in the linked post), or update the code to use print correctly for python 3

Comment: The error message says that you're missing the parenthesis, have you tried adding them? Also, that same script says `#Python 2.7.6` at the beggining, so use Python 2 instead of Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the parenthesis. In python 3 is neccesary

```
print(key + " : " + jData[key])
```

Comment: Yes adding parenthesis does help but then it gets stuck at another place. I feel  the issue is to do with not using the correct python version. Could you please help me rewrite the program for Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

You either:
- add the parenthesis that the error tells you to or
- use Python 2 as the script says in the firs line `#Python 2.7.6`

Comment: Yes adding parenthesis does help but then it gets stuck at another place. I feel  the issue is to do with not using the correct python version. Ok, let me uninstall this python version and install the older version.