# Curl not working when called with subprocess

Tags: python, curl, subprocess, python-2.6

I'm trying to call a REST api with curl. The api endpoint is dynamically generated in the program and a json file is also uploaded.

```
with open('data.json','w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data))
    cmd = 'curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @data.json {0}'.format(put_uri)
    print cmd
    p= subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()
    output, errors = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode != 0:
        print "Request failed"
```

Here i'm printing the command formed and when i run that command from shell, it is working as it is intended to do. But the same command is run with Popen throws some json validation error which is weired

```
{
  "success" : false,
  "message" : "Resource cannot be parsed due to Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)\n at [Source: java.io.StringReader@444c7495; line: 1, column: 2]"
}
```

Comment: This is dangerously insecure due to `shell=True` (think about what happens if your `put_uri` contains `$(rm -rf ~)`). Do you have any good reason to be doing so here?

Comment: Beyond that, this smells more like a problem with your data than with `subprocess`. Validate that both the URI and the `data.json` contents you test with from the command line are a precise match for the ones you're using here.

Comment: ...`/` characters aren't allowed in valid JSON either outside of quoted strings, but the message implies that your content contains one; that's a very real problem with the data, if true.

Comment: Anyhow: If you want us to be able to reproduce this, include a `data.json` and `put_uri` which can be used to recreate the problem; otherwise, this question is incomplete.

Comment: ...and to fix the security problem, remove `shell=True`, and pass an explicit array: `['curl', '-X', 'PUT', '-H', 'Content-Type: application/json', '-d', '@data.json', str(put_uri)]`

Comment: Oooh! One potential problem here is that you aren't closing/flushing your `data.json` file handle before calling `curl`.

Comment: Why to call `curl` through `subprocess.Popen` or similar, when there are libraries for REST api calls? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python

Comment: When i copy and paste the printed command on shell, it uses the same uri and data.json, So how is it creating a problem when call with Popen?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy tried that, not working

Comment: @AmalTs, I didn't say it would fix the problem you asked about here, I said it would fix your security bug. Or by "that" do you mean calling `f.flush()`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your second suggestion worked. I moved the `curl` command outside the `with`. In fact i didn't close the file handle which created the problem

Comment: @AmalTs, they were two different suggestions for very different things. If you aren't applying the first one, you still have a security bug.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala I was limited to use curl due some restrictions in our environment

Comment: @CharlesDuffy removed `shell=True` also. I just added that only for testing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code isn't ensuring that the JSON is fully written to disk before calling `curl`.

Either use `f.flush()` or `f.close()` following the `f.write(json.dumps(data))`.