# How to make api call in python?

Tags: python, apache-tika

I have ran tika server in my machine and call api using terminal which is working fine. I am able to extract text from image and pdf. But, I want to implement the api call in my python application.

```
curl -T price.xls http://localhost:9998/tika --header "Accept: text/plain"
```

Above is api call that i have to make. I can run this in my terminal and works fine but how to implement in python application. I have installed and tried requests.

```
API_URL = 'http://localhost:9998/tika'
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
tika_client = TikaApp(file_jar=join(APP_ROOT,'../tika-app-1.19.jar'))
data = {
    "url": join(APP_ROOT,'../static/image/a.pdf')
}
response = requests.put(API_URL, data)
print(response.content)
```

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you :)

error output

```
INFO  tika (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
WARN  tika: Text extraction failed
org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unexpected RuntimeException from org.apache.tika.server.resource.TikaResource$1@475b0e2
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:282)
at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:143)
at org.apache.tika.server.resource.TikaResource.parse(TikaResource.java:402)
at org.apache.tika.server.resource.TikaResource$5.write(TikaResource.java:513)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.BinaryDataProvider.writeTo(BinaryDataProvider.java:177)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.writeMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1391)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.serializeMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:246)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.processResponse(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:122)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:84)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:90)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:247)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:79)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:205)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
at org.apache.tika.server.resource.TikaResource$1.parse(TikaResource.java:128)
at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:280)
... 37 more
ERROR Problem with writing the data, class org.apache.tika.server.resource.TikaResource$5, ContentType: text/plain
```

Comment: Don't you need to pass in the payload data as a keyword argument? (`data=data`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a request to a RESTful API using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the data(payload), header.

```
url = 'http://localhost:9998/tika/......'
headers = {"Accept: text/plain"}
response = requests.put(url,data = data, headers=headers)
```

Have glance at this [Making a request to a RESTful API using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python)

Comment: when I run it from terminal i get    INFO  tika (autodetecting type) .   but when i call from python app i am getting     INFO  tika (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). how can i convert to autodetecting type

Comment: Can u attach both the outputs/screenshots? so that I can understand it.

Comment: i have edit my question with error output, please have a look

Comment: It seems you are not passing headers param.

Comment: i did that, but forget to update that one,

 headers = {"Accept": "text/plain"}
 data = {
     "url": join(APP_ROOT,'../static/image/a.pdf')
 }
 response = requests.put(API_URL, data=data, headers=headers)

still the same error

Comment: Your application is unable to read that pdf, it's unable to parse it. may be you need to change the way you read the pdf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181618/discussion-between-sheik-arbaz-and-lama-madan).