# Sharepoint calendar api with python

Tags: python, sharepoint

Is there a way to extract a sharepoint calendar? If possible with python. I haven't found something on the internet.

Maybe its possible to do that with a rest API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get calendar items through REST API. SharePoint has rich REST API.
SharePoint calendar it is just list items. You can work with it like with other lists items.

```
https://<server>/<web>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list_display_name>')/items
```

To this query you can add any additional params. Like $select to select specific fields, $expand to connect to related lists, $filter to filter items, $orderby to sort.

Here you can see official documentation and examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/determine-sharepoint-rest-service-endpoint-uris
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests

I don't know how to call Python request to RESTful services. I think you can use python "requests" lib. 
Like here:
https://realpython.com/api-integration-in-python/
[Making a request to a RESTful API using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python)