# How do I remotely execute a prespecified command with authentication across a local network on Linux?

Tags: linux, authentication, networking

I have two Debian Linux servers on the same network. I would like server A to execute this command on server B: `run.sh VARIABLE`, and it needs to be able to process the output of said command. The script `run.sh` is on server B I do not want its contents to be visible to server A. I need there to be some kind of authentication between these two machines as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specs are somewhat vague. Assuming that `run.sh` exists somewhere on `server B`, the easiest would be to use an `ssh forced command` and using a key-pair for the ssh connection.

You define the forced command in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `server B` and pull the `VARIABLE` out of `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` in `run.sh`.

`server A` never gets to see `run.sh`, is able to pass arguments to `run.sh`. and running `run.sh` is all it can ever do ...

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest and fastest way you can accomplish this is to setup a standalone python REST server. On the client side you can use any client, even curl or python requests.

[How to make a simple Python REST server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60537557/how-to-make-a-simple-python-rest-server-and-client)

As authentication it can be as simple as requiring a username and password in the JSON fields.