# Calling Azure logic app from Azure Python HTTP trigger function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I want to call an Azure logic app from Azure python based HTTP trigger function. Here is the end line (returning statement) of my python function which is returning expected value:

```
        return func.HttpResponse(successres)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(failedsres)
```

Now I want to call a HTTP trigger based logic app with passing 'successres' as JSON body.

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a callable endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint#create-a-callable-endpoint) for your App and call it.

Some more [details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres).

Comment: Thanks @Kashyap for the response. However my question is that only "How to call it". I know how to create a callable endpoint but not sure how to call it as function ends with a return statement.

Comment: @vivekmishra That part would be a simple http call with appropriate headers/auth etc. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python) for some examples and RTM (steps 7 & 8 in "details here" link above) for authentication etc.