# How to parse all the .gitlab-ci.yml files from all the repositories that i have access to?

Tags: python, gitlab, yaml

How to parse all the .gitlab-ci.yml files from all the repositories that i have access to?
I was searching documentation to do it using a python script but no luck.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the API.

First, you retrieve all projects, using the [projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) endpoint.
Should be something like this (these are curl examples, as I don't know python, but I expect you know what to do by them)

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects?membership=true"
```

Then you loop over the response, and for each project you use the [repository files endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html#get-file-from-repository) to get the gitlab-ci.yaml.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/13083/repository/files/gitlab-ci%2Eyaml?ref=master"
```

Then all you need is a good YAML interpreter, and that should be already answered here: [How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python)

Edit: For those who, like me, don't know python, this seems to be a helpful explanation in how to call a restful API in python: [Making a request to a RESTful API using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)