# Download or export Azure databricks notebooks to my local machine in Python using REST API

Tags: python, azure-databricks

I need to automate a way to download Azure Databricks notebooks using Python to my local machine. Please let me know if there are any ways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an API endpoint to export a notebook.

Refer to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace#--export

Here's how to make API requests with Python: [Making a request to a RESTful API using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17301938/making-a-request-to-a-restful-api-using-python)