# Create a product with Shopware 6 API in Python?

Tags: python, shopware6

Hey i want to use the shopware 6 api to fill my store with products. Sadly i cant get from reading the documentation on how to use the api in python. Im talking about this https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzA4NTUy-product-data where a payload is specified, but i cant get from the doc on how to authenticate on python or how to post the payload.

Comment: There's a section on authentication: https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEwODA3NjQx-authentication. There's a section on Request & Response Structure: https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzAzNDU1-request-and-response-structure. Then search for "making requests to APIs using python", which will lead to results like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17301938/2745495

Comment: There is a third-party community library that I haven't tried or verified personally, but it looks quite promising and has extensive documentation.

Maybe worth having a look - https://github.com/bitranox/lib_shopware6_api_base.

Answer (score 0):

For my personal use I have created a very simple Python abstraction for the Shopware API, find it here: https://github.com/aragon999/python-shopware/
Note there is currently no installer or anything, I might add something in the future.

I will quickly outline the most important steps for authentication using API credentials. For simplicity assume we have a method [`unauthenticated_call()`](https://github.com/aragon999/python-shopware/blob/9402e6155015209eb0193763275986d9cc1e646a/shopware.py#L47) which does an non authenticated call to the Shopware API:

1. First you should obtain the bearer-token [using an API request to `oauth/token`](https://github.com/aragon999/python-shopware/blob/9402e6155015209eb0193763275986d9cc1e646a/shopware.py#L87):

   ```py
   unauthenticated_call("oauth/token", fields={
       "grant_type": "client_credentials",
       "client_id": self.key_id,
       "client_secret": self.key_secret,
   })["access_token"]
   ```
2. Now add to any API call which should be authenticated (using the `access_token` obtained in the previous step):

   ```py
   {
       "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json",
   }
   ```
3. The token bearer token itself is only valid for 10 minutes, once it is not valid anymore the API will respond with [status `401`](https://github.com/aragon999/python-shopware/blob/9402e6155015209eb0193763275986d9cc1e646a/shopware.py#L38), when this happens you should [create a new token](https://github.com/aragon999/python-shopware/blob/9402e6155015209eb0193763275986d9cc1e646a/shopware.py#L82). For password authentication you should use the `refresh_token`.